# Is the left topology base in Q

Tags: general-topology

Is $\{(-\infty,a) : a \in \mathbb{Q}\}$ a base for a topology or not? and Why?
I tried it in $\Bbb R$ and it is a base, and I know that $\Bbb Q$ and $\Bbb R$ are equivalent. So it must be a base, right?

Comment: It is a basis of a topology but not of the usual one.

Comment: As a complement of @Berci comment : for example, $(a,b)$ is not open for the topology generated by your basis.

Comment: "Q and R are equivalent" what? Are we talking about rationals and reals? They are not even of the same cardinality. What exactly do you mean?

Comment: In the left topology they are equivalent, or not !!

Comment: No, they're not "equivalent", their cardinality is different.

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed the base for a topology on $\Bbb R$. It clearly covers $\Bbb R$ and the collection is closed under binary intersections:

$$(-\infty, a_1) \cap (-\infty, a_2)= (-\infty, \min(a_1,a_2))$$

So the two usual conditions are satisfied easily.

In the topology $\mathcal{T}$ it generates, in fact all subsets $(-\infty, r)$, for a real $r$ are also open, because if $r$ is irrational we can approximate it by rationals from below, say $q_n \uparrow r$ and then $$(-\infty,r)=\bigcup_n (-\infty, q_n)$$ is in $\mathcal{T}$ too, being a union of basic opens. So it generates the left-topology on $\Bbb R$ and is an alternative (countable) base for it.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to prove the following: A collection $B$ of subsets of a set $X$ is a base for a topology on $X$ iff

$(i).$ $\cup B=X.$ That is, each $x\in X$ belongs to at least one member of $B$.

$(ii).$ Whenever $b_1,b_2\in B$ and $x\in b_1\cap b_2$ there exists $b_3\in B$ such that $x\in b_3\subset b_1\cap b_2.$

Observe that if $b_1\cap b_2 \in B$ whenever $b_1,b_2\in B$ then (ii) is satisfied by letting $b_3=b_1\cap b_2.$